# pthread with struct argument not working

Tags: c++, pthreads

- I have read some posts and it seems it is still not working properly for this simple pthread problem that I am working. Any suggestions as to where I did wrong? I keep getting garbage instead of numbers from 0 to 5, randomly.

  ```
  #define num_threads 6

  pthread_mutex_t mutex;
  pthread_t threads[num_threads];

  struct argument
  {
   int value;
  };

  void* fun(void* args)
  {pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
   argument* args2=(argument*)args;
   cout<<args2->value<<endl;
   pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
  }

  int main()
  {pthread_mutex_init(&mutex,NULL);
   for (long i=0;i<num_threads;i++)
      {argument* args=new argument;
       args->value=i;
       pthread_create(&(threads[i]),NULL,fun,(void*) args);
      delete args;
      }

   for (long i=0;i<num_threads;i++)
     {pthread_join(threads[i],NULL);}
   pthread_exit(NULL);
  }
  ```

Answer (score 1):

You're not handling memory correctly;

```cpp
// Allocate memory for argument
argument* args=new argument; 

// Set value
args->value=i;

// Create a thread, passing a pointer to argument as a parameter
pthread_create(&(threads[i]),NULL,fun,(void*) args);

// Free the argument you just passed.
// The pointer you just passed is no longer pointing to valid memory
// when the thread actually starts.
delete args;
```

In this case, allocating/passing the argument as you do, but removing the `delete` in the main thread and allowing the thread to delete its own argument *once it has finished using it* is probably the easiest option.

Comment: Thank you! Now I see what is happening!